# How to handle cache stampede when using hazelcast?

Tags: caching, hazelcast

My spring service is using hazelcast(embedded cluster) as local cache.

When the cache expires due to TTL, if a large number of user requests come at once, the requests are transferred to the DB to update the cache. (cache stampede)

For this reason, I thought about applying the PER algorithm, but from my understanding, the algorithm seems to be meaningful when the cache expiration time can be different for each node.
However, it seems that hazelcast cluster cache cannot be applied because it uses a cache synchronized on a per-cluster basis. Is that correct?

So, what strategy should hazlecast take to handle cache stampede?

Comment: If you've expired a lot of entries that you then need, doesn't this mean the TTL is too low ?

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast provides the following method:

```
put(K, V, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)
```

which allows you to specify a TTL on per-entry level. You can e.g. randomize the value in some interval which would prevent the cache stampede.